# Codename One iOS 15 Debug Build Won't Open

Tags: java, codenameone, ios15

Since updating my iPad to iOS 15, I can no longer run the debug version of my app on it (the prod version works fine). It gives me an error saying "The developer of this app needs to update it to work with this version of iPadOS."

Googling this error, I found a post about going to 64 bit by default to resolve this, back from 2017 (https://www.codenameone.com/blog/moving-to-64bit-by-default.html)

I checked my app settings and I don't have the hint that would force a 32bit build (ios.debug.archs=armv7). Is there anything else I can check to see why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably related to this: https://www.reddit.com/r/cn1/comments/ori4ve/ios_14_support/

Try the `ios.zsign=true` build hint.