# [codenameone]IPadOs 15 not supported in app build

Tags: codenameone

Just received IPAD 9th Gen running IpadOs 15.

Updated all certificates, verified installs work on IpadOs 14.71 on Ipad Gen 6

When Installing (Debug Build) on the 9th Gen IpadOs 15, get message dialog (Attached)

Thoughts?

Best Regards[image: Install Error Dialog]

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69289761/codename-one-ios-15-debug-build-wont-open

Comment: Thanks. Adding ios.zsign=true build hint. worked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Codename One iOS 15 Debug Build Won't Open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69289761/codename-one-ios-15-debug-build-wont-open)